# How to remove components in page using React.js?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, custom-error-pages

I have an error page and I want to remove the nav and sidebar from it. How can I do that?

i tried to use in css display:none, but it didn't work

Comment: Please share some of your code and what you have tried so far so we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you conditionally render your nav and sidebar component

Use `window.location.pathname` to get the current page.

Do something like:

```
{!window.location.pathname === '/404page' ? <YourComponent/> : null}
```